# button tag not working in IE7 (using asp.net mvc )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-7

I have this ASP.net MVC project that requires a wizard like interface...
So I am using the next ,back button inside the form.

And I am trapping the button name in my controller to do the required action.

But the problem is the **button click is working in IE8,chrome,ff but not in IE7.**

It doesnt seem to fire the postback...do I have to explicity fire the postback on Onclick?
Anyone knows why button click not firing in IE7 ???

thanks I appreciate any answer..

Here's the psuedo code I am using...

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ListEntries","Home",FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "MyForm" } )) {%>
                        <button name="button" value="next">Next</button>
                        <button name="button" value="back">Back</button>
  //blah....blh...blah...


<% } %>

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ListEntries( string button)
    {
        if (button == "next")
            return RedirectToAction("doNextAction");
    else
    if (button == "back")
    return RedirectToAction("goBack");
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this link http://www.peterbe.com/plog/button-tag-in-IE makes me believe that in IE7 the button element will not post a single string to your controller so would not match the signature of your controller method, have you tried (as is suggested here) using input elements of type submit instead?

its not something I have seen myself but it seems to match your issue

Comment: Thanks...this link has some useful info I need...I will try some of their solution..I need button because of the value field different from the displayed text field. The above code is just a sample.

Comment: Update: For those who are still looking, this is how I solved it..<input type="hidden" name="actiontype" value="none" id="ietype"> <button type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById ('ietype').value='Your value';" name="next">Next</button> Found it from the link above...Thanks pharabus for the link...On a side note how didnt google fetch me the above link...Damn Google:)

Answer (score 2):

Button tags in IE (v. 8, at least) will not work without an 'onclick' handler. Well, at least you can't simply wrap the button in an anchor tag.

Doesn't work:

```
<a href="link.html">
    <button>Click Me!</button>
</a>
```

Works:

```
<a href="link.html" onclick="javascript:window.location=this.href">
    <button>Click Me!</button>
</a>
```

Comment: It **is** against HTML5