# a href throught sent values not working in IE7 using code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, internet-explorer-7, codeigniter-url

I am trying to send values through "HREF"..  its not working in IE7.. 
But in Chrome and Mozilla .code is working fine

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/admin/show_particular_user_info/'.$row->user_info_id; ?>">
    <button class="btn btn-mini" type="button">view</button>
</a>
```

Controller Side :-

```
function show_particular_user_info($user_id)
    {
        $this->load->model('user_info_model');
        $data['records'] = $this->user_info_model->get_particular_record($user_id);

        $this->load->view('apang_report',$data);
    }
```

Comment: Define not working. Are you getting any sort of error?

Comment: No.. I am not getting any error.

Comment: @user1254919: What does the resulting `href` attribute look like?

Comment: Can you please tell us what is not working? You are posting server-side code, telling us it works in Chrome/FF and not in IE. 

Does the link not contain user_info_id? Does clicking on the link take you somewhere other than your controller? Or does your controller not work properly?

Comment: Why not view source in IE and see what it looks like, compared to FF? And if they look same, why not try opening the HREF directly in IE?

Comment: controller not work properly..no action working in IE.. when i click on View button @DavidHoude

Comment: try printing `user_id` does it carry the value?

Comment: In IE its not going to controller side as well.. its keep at same page.. no activity happening at controller side

Comment: show us the url generated in ie?

Comment: http://www.abcde.com/index.php/admin/show_particular_user_info/1 this is the url in IE @ganeshrj

Comment: are you using iframe?

Comment: no.. i am not using IFrame

Comment: Try echoing out the value of $user_id in your controller, and then see if the value is the same in both IE and chrome, you could also try making it a standard link, without the <button> tag and see if that has any effect.

Comment: I did echoing on controller side.. but in IE  nothing is happening on button click .. its stay on same page.. without doing any activity... but when i do in Chrome its shows me a proper value 1 @Re0sless

Comment: You should read this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4937764/2098 it may be that your <a><button>view</button></a> is to blame, try it without the button tag and see what happens.

Comment: Hey @Re0sless Thank you Very ver Much.. now it working ...U rocks..

Comment: Doesn't work:

<a href="link.html">
    <button>Click Me!</button>
</a>
Works:

<a href="link.html" onclick="javascript:window.location=this.href">
    <button>Click Me!</button>
</a>

Comment: No problem :) you may want to go up-vote the answer in the other question that helped you.

Comment: ohk thanks @Re0sless... i have less reputation to vote up.. :(

Comment: Ah OK I'll up-vote it for you then :)

Answer (score 0):

make some UI fixes like below

```
 <button class="btn btn-mini" type="button"> <a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/admin/show_particular_user_info/'.$row->user_info_id; ?>">
   view
</a></button>
```